# Auto 301 on category moves

Tags: category, 301-redirect

I am looking for an automated method of producing 301 redirects after a category change. I have a client who is consistently moving his categories and does not want to manually input redirects in URL management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to write an observer on `catalog_category_save_before` that gets all products from that category, retrieves the old URL paths, and adds those to the `core_url_rewrite` table